# Ajax file upload not being store in the directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm in the process of building a function in uploading a file(CSV) using AJAX. This is just a rough code since that I'm working and currently following a tutorial. I'm using XAMPP for server side languages

After executing i'm getting an alert that displays (obect FormData) inside and aside from that, the uploads directory is empty after submitting the file. Project currently has three items. (Uploads Folder, index.php and upload.php)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file-uploading" type="file" name="fileUploading" />
    <button id="upload" value="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#file-uploading').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    alert(form_data);                             
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', 
                dataType: 'text',  
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(){
                    console.log('success'); 
                }
     });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<body>

<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br/>';
    }

    else {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    }

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your form element needs the enctype declaration i.e. <form enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Comment: Yeah, declared that inside my form element before you mentioned it. Still getting the same result

Comment: try `$('#file-uploading').files[0];`

Comment: Same result, but this time the first alert box doesn't show up `alert(form_data);`

Answer (score 0):

I test successful.I think "uploads" permissions is not right.You should do:

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data uploads

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out on enctype attribute on form.

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 // your content
</form>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I added that earlier and still got the same result

Comment: Then try changing the permission of the upload directory. Set it to 777.

Comment: how do I check that? I'm using xampp on my local machine for server side languages

Comment: you can dump the file property and exit in the server side. print_r($_FILES); exit('exiting'); and see the file attributes.

Comment: Did some debugging using "is_writable". So far the file i'm trying to access is writable